# What is the "shell" function of "GNU make" doing on a Windows system?

Tags: windows, shell, makefile

I am confused about the shell function of *GNU make* on a Windows system. Here is my example Makefile:

```
X1 := $(shell date)
X2 := $(shell cat Makefile)
X3 := $(shell dir p*)
X4 := $(shell ls p*)

example_1:
    @echo $(X1)

example_2:
    @echo $(X2)

example_3:
    @echo $(X3)

example_4:
    @echo $(X4)
```

`make example 1` is still ok:

> Tue Mar 22 15:45:41 2016

According to the [documentation of the shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html), `make example 2` should list the contents of the Makefile.
This is *almost* the case:

> X1 := X2 := X3 := X4 := example_1: @echo example_2: @echo example_3:
>   @echo example_4: @echo

`dir p*` on the console gives:

```
24.11.2015  18:17            47.814 plot.png
22.02.2016  16:53            58.039 Plot_1.png
13.01.2016  12:46            63.043 Plot_2.png
13.01.2016  12:47            62.913 Plot_3.png
16.01.2016  00:21               199 progetto46E.csv
               5 File(s),        232.008 Bytes
               0 Folder(s), 60.907.466.752 Bytes free
```

But `make example 3` doesn't find `dir`. Instead, `make example 4` gives *almost* the result of `dir p*`:

> plot.png progetto46E.csv

But this is case sensitive and contains only the filenames. And `ls` belongs to UNIX, not Windows, but is almost 
equivalent to `dir`.

Is there a function of *GNU make* that does on a Windows system what `shell` does on a UNIX system?

Comment: are you running this under cygwin? `cat` would work on Windows unless you have cygwin, or installed some aliases/batch files to simulate unix commands under windows.

Comment: I am not sure what "cygwin" is. I got "make" when I tried to build "R" from source following [these instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Getting-the-tools). Perhaps this involves "cygwin".

Comment: @mra68, if you don't know what is cygwin, then how do you expect to run unix style code in windows?

Comment: @Joel: Like almost everybody I owe more than one machine. On some of them the operating system is Linux.